# android - get package names of matching services

Tags: android

I want to get the package names of all the apps that contain a service matching an Intent. I know `PackageManager` has the `queryIntentServices` API, and the returned `ResolveInfo` has a field called `serviceInfo`, but that only contains some flags and permissions. Is there a way to get the package name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String packageName = resolveInfo.serviceInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
```

Answer (score 0):

ResolveInfo also has field called "resolvePackageName" that holds the package name for the service that matched the provided android-intent.

```
//Sample Code
PackagrManager mPM = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolvedServicesInfo = mPM.queryIntentServices(Intent intent, int flags);
String pacakgename = resolvedServicesInfo.get(0).resolvePackageName;
```